# Getting list in UITableView of saved video files in project iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Here I am trying to get the list of files which I have saved in my project.

[image: Files List]

As you can see in the screenshot I have some video files, which I have copied to my project. I want to display these files list in a tableview. And in didselectRowMethod I want to get the path of the selected video file and then want to use it to play.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can archive it like this :

```
NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *dirContents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRoot error:nil];
```

Now `dirContents` will hold paths to all files.

If you want only movies you can do like this:

```
NSPredicate *f = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.mp4'"];
NSArray *videos = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:f];
```

Your table view datasource should point to `videos` or `dirContents`
And in your

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath :(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *bundlePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];

NSString *pathToVideo=[bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[videos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];      

}
```

Comment: Thanks Bogdan, but it only contains the name and extension of the video file. How can I get path. Actually I want to save the path so that if user has selected some video from tableview list, then its path will be saved for the user so that he would play it later.

Comment: Here you go, now you should have a full path to selected component